# Composer Rest Server JWT Authentication Angular 5

Tags: hyperledger-composer, passport-jwt

is anyone in here knows how to access the url below using angular 5? I want to access the url and retrieved the response cookies of it. Tried it over and over again but it seems like the cookies is not being retrieved. Thanks in advance.

http://localhost:3000/auth/jwt/callback?query=

I tried using postman and I successfully get the access_token. I have no idea how to do the same in typescript.

Comment: What does your network tab say in your devtools? That's probably going to be your biggest help, especially if its a CORs issue

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am actually now getting the 3 cookies. I used an HTTP_INTERCEPTOR as mentioned in this article,

https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

My problem now is how to extract those cookies using typescript.